# Customize protractor result html report?

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, protractor

I want to have a summarized test report in addition to htmlReport created using Jasmine2HtmlReporter , how is it possible ?

Total no of test run , passed , failed etc.. ?

As of now it is generated using Jasmine2HtmlReporter

```
 onPrepare: function() {
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './protractor-result',
            takeScreenshots: false
        })
    );
rootElement: 'body'
}
```

Comment: Make your own reporter, it's very easy.  https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

Comment: Or edit the package of the current reporter you have now.

Comment: Also You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-allure-reporter